# How do I validate an OAuth LinkedIn login performed on a mobile device?

Tags: authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

I have a mobile app which uses LinkedIn's OAuth API to allow users to login with LinkedIn.

Given that the entire login transaction takes place on the mobile device, how can my server validate that the login was actually successful?

Comment: Is anyone find any solution ?